# Using Eloquent Relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Laravel 8**

I have a couple models using eloquent relationships.

A `User` which can have many blog posts

```
public function blogPosts() {
    return $this->hasMany(BlogPost::class);
}
```

And a `BlogPost` which belongs to the author

```
public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

My issue is that when I attempt to use one of these relationships, I am returned an empty object.

We can focus on the `belongsTo()` relationship.

I am attempting to use this relationship here:

```
class BlogPostResourceCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return $this->collection->map(function($post) { 
            return [
                'id' => $post->id,
                'author' => $post->author(),
                'title' => $post->title,
            ];
        });
    }
}
```

Why am I getting an empty object for `author`?

Edit: the blog post table does have a foreign key user id column.

Comment: just change `$post->author()` to `$post->author`

Comment: @Joseph I have just tried that and receive a `null` value. The users/authors of the blog posts do exist in the DB

Comment: please check the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the problem is `laravel` by default get the relation from the method name and you add custom names so to fix it you need to add the second `argument` for each relation like this

### User Model

```
public function blogPosts() {
   return $this->hasMany(BlogPost::class, 'user_id');
}
```

### BlogPost

```
public function author() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

At the end in your `BlogPostResourceCollection` you need to access the `author` data all you need is to write `->author` not `->author()`

for more info, you could check the `One-To-Many` relation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: Just for more information in the answer, what does Laravel expect by default instead of `author()`? `user()`?

Comment: when you write it `author` laravel will add the foreign key as `author_id` not `user_id` that is what the problem comes from